# Cell array reshaping

Tags: matlab

If I have a 20x1 cell matrix where each cell is a 1x50 cell matrix, what would be the best way to form a 20x50 cell matrix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your cell array is stored in the variable `cellArray`, you can use the function [VERTCAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/vertcat.html) like so:

```
cellMatrix = vertcat(cellArray{:});
```